# Spring conditional EventListener with reference to called Bean

Tags: java, spring, event-handling

I have dynamically published an arbitrary number of beans of the same class in my application context, via a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`.
These beans act as an EventListener, but each bean should react only to appropriate events.
Which events are appropriate depends on the value stored in the concrete bean.

My bean class:

```
public class DynamicBeanClass {
    private final String addressId;

    public DynamicBeanClass (String addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    @EventListener(condition = "#event.addressId.matches('^TEST_' + #this.addressId + '$')")
    public void on(EventClass event) {
       System.err.println("Hello from " + addressId);
    }
}
```

The `#this` resolves to the `EventExpressionRootObject`, thus the `addressId` is not accessible.
Using `#addressId` yields `null`.

Is it possible to access the bean upon which the `@EventListener`s condition is evaluated within the SPEL expression?
If not, what alternatives should i consider?

Comment: Have you tried `#root` instead of `#this`.?

Comment: @M.Deinum `#root` resolves, like `#this` to the `EventExpressionRootObject`, too.